# plotting discontinuous functions

Tags: python, numerics, numpy

I need help plotting the [Heaviside function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function):

[image]

Real analysis often involves constructing bizarre functions which are intuitively correct, but ultimately wrong.  See the great book [Counterexamples in Analysis](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486428753).

---

I wrote a `numpy` script to plot the function $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} H\left(x - \frac{1}{n}\right)$ to illustrate some concepts in real analysis.  This is in a response to another question on math.stackexchange:

- [Demonstrating Continuity Properties of $f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty [a_n H(x - x_n)]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/262121)

Here is an example with an accompanying plot:

```
B = [ [1,n] for n in range(1,50) ]

N = 1000
y = np.zeros(N)
count = 1
for b in B:
    x = np.zeros(N)
    x[ np.arange(b[0]*1.0*N/b[1], N).astype(int)]=count**-2
    y += x
    count += 1

plt.plot(np.arange(0,1,1.0/N),y)
plt.axis("Equal")
```

[image: Heaviside function]

How can I remove the vertical lines and really show the discontinuity?

Comment: I edited my answer to show how to plot your specific function using `np.nan`s. Would you mind reviewing the existing answers and selecting a good one? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

As long as you know the exact positions of the discontinuities, you just have to set the jump positions to `nan` in `x`, `y` or both. You can set this manually in the desired positions or use some criteria - for example, you can use the `np.diff` function to calculate the difference between contiguous positions in an array. For the simple case of the Heaviside function:

```
def heaviside(x):
    """See http://stackoverflow.com/a/15122658/554319"""
    y = 0.5 * (np.sign(x) + 1)
    y[np.diff(y) >= 0.5] = np.nan
    return y

x = np.linspace(-1, 1)
plt.plot(x, heaviside(x))
plt.ylim(-1, 2)
```

[image: Heaviside function with matplotlib]

Using this in your specific example:

```
def U(x, n):
    return sum([heaviside(x - 1 / i) / i ** 2 for i in range(1, n)])

N = 1000
x = np.linspace(0, 1, N)
plt.plot(x, U(x, 50))
```

[image: OP function]

Comment: Can you also get the filled-in and empty circles respectively? See the image in the question: there needs to be a filled circle at (0, 0.5), and empty ones at (0,0) and (0,1).

Comment: This now throws "IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0;...", but using `y[:-1][np.diff(y) >= 0.5] = np.nan` in the definition of `heavyside` should fix it.

Answer (score 3):

Getting rid of the vertical lines in this plot would involve finding all the discontinuities and then plotting each segment in a separate call to `plt.plot`.

Another, less elegant, solution is to plot points instead of lines. Since the points are very close together (high value of `N`), they will look like they form a line. To do this, replace `plt.plot(np.arange(0,1,1.0/N), y)` with `plt.plot(np.arange(0,1,1.0/N), y, '.k')` (the `.`tells `plot` to use dots, `k` is for black). This is what you'll get:

[image]

Comment: Can you also get the filled-in and empty circles respectively? See the image in the question: there needs to be a filled circle at (0, 0.5), and empty ones at (0,0) and (0,1).

Answer (score 1):

You can ' hold ' the plot and plot each component separately. Loop over the different functions and plot.